# reading a text file and store its content in an unoredered_map in c++

Tags: c++, unordered-map

I have a text file that look like:

```
car 1 2 3
truck 4 5 8
van 7 8 6 3
```

I want to read this file and store its values in an unordere_map that is declared as:

```
unordered_map <string , vector<int>> mymap
```

I want to store the type of the vehicle as a key while the the rest of the numbers as values inside the vector for that key.

what I have done so far is:

```
int main()
{
    ifstream file("myfile");    
    string line;
    unordered_map <string, vector<int>> mymap;
    while(std::getline(file, line))
    {
        std::istringstream iss(line);
        std::string token;
        while (iss >> token)
        {
       // I don't know how to store the first token as key while the rest as values
        }
    }  
}
```

Comment: Put another loop inside the `while()`  that reads the numbers.

Comment: thanks alot for your reply. @Some programmer dude has provided an easier solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the inner loop in the wrong place (and don't really need it at all).

First get the "key" in a simple input operation. Then read all *integers* and add them to a vector. Lastly after all data for the line have been read you add the key and value (vector) to the map.

Something like this:

```
// Get the key
std::string token;
iss >> token;

// Get the integers
std::vector<int> values(std::istream_iterator<int>(iss),
                        std::istream_iterator<int>());
// Or use a plain loop to read integers and add them to the vector one by one

// Add the key and vector to the map
mymap[token] = values;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It work as what I wanted. I added another loop and pushed back the int values inside the vector "values.push_back(token)" one by one.

Comment: @emadalamoudi You don't need the inner loop to read the integers. Just do as I show in my example and all numbers will be read and added to the vector automatically.